# Dynamically created <li> elements eventattaching with on() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, attachevent

I am trying for 2-3 hours on this script. It creates ul and append li to it. Then i try to attach eventListeners (click) which will be a trigger for some function. 
On my local try callback function only retrieves last li values. Is it a looping problem or jquery has any known issues with .on() ?

```
The Container ul tag below
<ul id="container">
    <li>emtyp statically created</li>
</ul>
```

Here is js model js below:

```
var xy=1;
for(xy=1; xy<10; xy++){
$("#container").append('<li id="li_'+xy+'">'+xy+'</li>');   
    $("#li_"+xy).on("click",function(){alert(xy)});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/caglaror/c8jg6f8y/1/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: The event handler are called correctly... the issue is the use of closure variable xy... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/az17mb0p/2/

Comment: jquery way - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/az17mb0p/4/

Comment: After after hours. Still can't solve my issue. Is there anybody help me directly on my codes?

Comment: No. I tried both two methods that you gave. But not succeed.

Comment: can you edit my fiddle to recreate your case

Comment: I try to convert my original code to your example http://jsfiddle.net/caglaror/az17mb0p/5/

Comment: Some how event delegation method works. Please donte waste your time. It works for now. Thank you very much. May i contact to youon linkedIn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the event to the `ul` itself, passing in the `li` element as a parameter:

```
$('ul#container').on('click', '#li_' + xy, function() { ... });
```

This is known as ***[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)***.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

If each `li` element will have the same `click` function, you can move that click handler outside of your `for` loop completely.

As a side note you can also move that `var` declaration down into your `for` loop like so:

```
for (var xy = 1; ...; ...)
```

Comment: After reading whole night over my question, i got the point. Whenever a user actions includes inserting or removing elements from the working area we should use `event delegation`. But if we are using such thing like ajax to reload all ingredients of container element, we can use closure. In my real application situation, i am reloading data with json and then recreating inner elements (li). So i am going to use closure variables. @Arun and @James you are great guys ;)